# Where is the 'logout' link?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, logout

I was on the SuperUser homepage, and noticed that there was no logout link. Came to meta and there's still no logout link. It's now missing on the StackOverflow page too. What's going on?

Comment: Okay, found the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing. The link is shifted to the user profile. For goodness sake, please bring back the link to the main page!

Comment: It's moved back to the main page, under the hamburger button: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/10911/how-do-i-log-out-of-this-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And it's now in a drop down from your username at the top of the page. Much better!

Comment: Much better indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

From [Logout Link Now Missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing):

> The link has been moved to your user profile. Click on your username at the top of the page and you will see the link there.

Answer (score 3):

It's now on [your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80647/why-is-logout-moved-to-my-profile-page).

Click your DisplayName in the header.

You'll come to a page that has the following links just left of your About Me section:

> edit | add openid | log out

Reason? Real estate in the header is premium and the "log out" link wasn't being used as much.