# What happened to the log out link?

Tags: support, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the 'logout' link?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2126/where-is-the-logout-link)

Where did the logoff link go on the Stack Overflow sites?

I don't see it anymore.