# How do I log out of this site?

Tags: support, logout

I accidentally created a user when trying to log in, and now I can't find how to log out...  I can't find a logout button.  So how do I log out?

Here is some extra text because it won't let me post this question.  It's complaining about it not meeting quality standards.  It's an incredibly simple question that should be painfully obvious--however it isn't hence me asking.  Hopefully now this is enough text to let me post this question.

Comment: Click "Stack Exchange" on top. Find "Super User". To the right of that it says "Log Out". Click that.

Comment: I've to admit it's a little bit hidden... If you have created accidentally a new user maybe you want to remove it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the 'logout' link?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2126/where-is-the-logout-link)

Comment: @Mureinik: That's an old duplicate question.  The question is the same but the site has been modified since those posts and the answers are no longer correct.  Sending people there will cause confusion unless those answers are updated.

Answer (score 10):

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you have anything (questions, answers, reputation, loose change etc) with the other account, you can use the contact us link to ask for a merger.

Comment: Nice, what software is that?

Comment: [licecap](http://superuser.com/a/657800/10165) of course.

Answer (score 2):

To **Log Out**

- Click "Stack Exchange" on top. It comes a menu
- On the top right there are `blog` `chat` and `Log Out` links

Maybe just you have created this account accidentally you can remove it.

**References**

1. [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)
2. [Deleting account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)